# Problema con javascript y laravel - Guardar token

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-8

no se casi nada de javascript y esperaba encontrar ayuda aqui.
estoy trabajando con notifiaciones push, necesito guardar el token que genera y pasarlo por POST

Javascript:

```
function pedirPermiso(){
    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Se han haceptado las notificaciones");
        hideAlert();
        return messaging.getToken();
    }).then(function(token){
        console.log(token);
        guardarToken(token);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('No se ha recibido el permiso');
        showAlert();
    });
}
function guardarToken(token){
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('token',token);
    axios.post('/token',formData).then( respuesta=>{
        console.log(respuesta);
    }).catch( e=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Ruta para guardar:

```
Route::post('/token', 'savetoken@HomeController' )->name('token');
```

Controlador:

```
  public function savetoken()
{
        Notificaciones::insert([
          'user_id'  => 1,
          'token'        => ("token")
        ]);
  
        return back()->with('success', 'token saved successfully!');
}
```

Error en consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo pasar y guardar correctamente el token?

Comment: Ahora mismo, ¿cuál es el error que obtienes? Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta para aclarar mejor este punto.

Comment: En la consola me aparece: POST http://localhost/token 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu codigo javascript no tiene problemas, el problema es la funcion saveToken de tu controlador, para poder acceder a los parametros enviados en la solicitud POST debes importar la clase Request de laravel añadiendo la siguiente linea de codigo antes de tu clase

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Luego en tu función saveToken debes pasar la clase Request de la siguiente manera para poder acceder a la informacion de la solicitud HTTP. Al igual que si estas utilizando Eloquent te sugiero utilizar la funcion "create" para insertar nuevas filas en la tabla.

```
  public function savetoken(Request $request)
{
        Notificaciones::create([
          'user_id'  => 1,
          'token'    => $request->token
        ]);
  
        return back()->with('success', 'token saved successfully!');
}
```

Actualizo:

Tu codigo javascript en la solicitud HTTP debe incluir en su header el parametro csrf_token generado para cada usuario de tu aplicacion laravel. Para esto dentro de tu .blade debes incluir en el header un meta que guarde el csrf_token al generar el codigo html. Esta es la etiqueta que debes agregar dentro de tu header.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

luego debes editar tu solicitud HTTP e incluir el csrf-token generado para el usuario dentro de sus headers.

```
function guardarToken(token){
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('token',token);

    var config = {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"').content

        } 
    }

    axios.post('/token',formData, config).then( respuesta=>{
        console.log(respuesta);
    }).catch( e=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

te dejo enlaces de información relevante para el problema que estas teniendo te recomiendo leerlos para poder entender mejor el problema.

CSRF Protection Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf

HTTP Request Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#introduction

Documentación axios:
https://github.com/axios/axios

Saludos!

Comment: gracias por ayudar, pero ahora me sale, error: POST http://localhost/token 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Hola!, actualize la respuesta de tu pregunta te invito a leerla, la solicitud HTTP es negada debido a la proteccion CSRF de Laravel. Prueba la solucion que te planteo y me comentas cualquier cosa, saludos !

Comment: gracias, añadí los cambios de la protección CSRF pero aún sigue el error 401, no será un problema en la ruta o en el controlador?

Comment: acabo de darme cuenta de algo, inicie sesion con mi usuario en mi app de laravel y ahora me devuelve error POST http://localhost/token 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: tu ruta Route::post('/token', 'savetoken@HomeController' )->name('token');
esta al reves  primero se llama al controlador y luego a la función por lo que deberia ser HomeController@savetoken. Igualmente para saber con mas detalle lo que sucede, debes entrar a la pestaña "Network" en la herramienta de desarrollador del navegador, luego buscas la solicitud que falla, le haces click y le das a la pestaña "Preview", esto te mostrara el error en concreto que te entrega laravel en su modo debug, saludos.

Comment: si eso me di  cuenta solo y lo corregí. en el network me aparece:        https://i.imgur.com/gsABeoM.png                        {
    "message": "Server Error"
}{
    "message": "Server Error"
}

Comment: tambien me aparece este error:  https://i.imgur.com/kekNdWr.png

Comment: Revisa el archivo log de laravel, este se encuentra en storage/logs/laravel.log este deberia entregarte más detalles del error. Respecto al ultimo error, verifica que los datos de conexion a la base de datos en tu archivo .env sean correctos.

Comment: vi el error, lo corregi ejecuntando php artisan config:cache. Ahora guarda en la base de datos pero me pasa mal el valor del token, https://i.imgur.com/GxfBVbR.png

Comment: Verifica el parametro que se esta enviando y recuerda recuperarlo con Request de laravel utilizando $request->token , saludos.